# react-select 2 setting value/label

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am using react-select 2 and trying to set value on form that needs to perform update of some data fetched from server.

I have tried solution:

```
handleSelectChange(selectedOption){
 this.setState({ selectedOption });
}

const options = [
  { value: 'Value 1', label: 'Value 1' },
  { value: 'Value 2', label: 'Value 2' },

]

<Select
   options={options}
   onChange={(selectedOption)=>this.handleSelectChange(selectedOption)}
   autoFocus={true}
   value={options.find(option => option.value === data.valueTyppe)}

/>
```

By using this it is not possible to change (visualy) label in select input - value changes on select but label stays as one defined by data.ValueType.

Comment: Yes, everything works just label in Input is not changing. If selected option is for example Value 1, when I change it to Value 2 , value changes because I can see it saved in database, but label in input filed remains Value 1.

Comment: Aren't you suppose to pass `selectedOption` state into your `value` props in your `Select` component ?

Comment: data.ValueType is value fetched from server. It is saved data from options array of objects. I want to set that value in Select input, as default value, and then be able to change that value from one of the options defined. I manage to change value but label in input is not changing. Note data.ValueType is string.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem comes from not allowing full control of the Select input.The value of the Select input should be the component state value property, same as the onChange calback is.

```
return(
      <Select
      options={options}
      onChange={this.handleSelectChange}
      autoFocus={true}
      value={this.state.selectedOption}
   />
```

try this working [examle](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-germain-9ku5l)

Comment: Thank you for answer. But point is to set value that is fetched from server. Not to make Selec to work. It is working and I know how to configure it for usage but don't know how to set value to that saved in my DB and to be able to change selection and resave it (update). :)

Comment: Can you supply full example of your code?It's not quite clear.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this solution and it works for me. 
First Value/Label pair is set as on defined in options that have value === data.FacilityType (saved string in database).

Then it enables change of option where value/label pair is also updated in Select.

```
<Select
  options={options}
  onChange={(selectedOption)=>this.handleSelectChange(selectedOption)}
  autoFocus={true}
  defaultValue={options.find(option => option.value === data.facilityType)}

/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
<Select
  getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
  getOptionValue={option => option.id}
  options={items}
/>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).